# Atribuir valor em variável SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, inner

Como faço para fazer um *select* que atribua o valor "10" em todos da coluna jogos?

OBS: Sem dar *update* na tabela.

> ```
> /*minha_tabela*/
> codigo        jogos   
> ---------------------
>   1            10
>   2            10
>   3            10
>   4            10
>   5            10
>   6            10
> ```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Caro,

`select codigo, 10 as jogos from minha_tabela`

Funciona em SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

Se for necessário o uso de variável, como consta no título do tópico, eis uma abordagem:

```
-- código #1 (T-SQL)
declare @jogos int;
set @jogos= 10;

--
SELECT codigo, @jogos as jogos
  from minha_tabela;
```